# Getting the wrong values after SUM() query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm executing the following query:

```
SELECT 
                    MAX(table1.id) as id, 
                    clients.Username as account, 
                    table1.clientid, 
                    SUM(table1.symbols) as symbols, 
                    SUM(table1.tickets) as tickets, 
                    SUM(table1.cash) as cash, 
                    (SUM(CASE WHEN table2.memo = 'Withdraw' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)) AS withdraw,
                    (SUM(CASE WHEN table2.memo = 'Depos' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)) AS depos,
                FROM 
                    table1 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    (                       
                        clients 
                            LEFT JOIN 
                            table2 
                            ON 
                        clients.Fidx = table2.clientid 
                        AND 
                        table2.date >= '01-09-2016' 
                 AND 
                    table2.date <= '01-09-2017'

                    )                                                                              
                ON 
                    clients.Fidx = table1.clientid 
                WHERE 
                    table1.tradedate >= '01-09-2016' 
                 AND 
                    table1.tradedate <= '01-09-2017'
                GROUP BY 
                    table1.clientid, clients.Username, table2.clientid 
                ORDER BY 
                    clients.Username;
```

And I want to get a simple result table combined of three tables:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| account |withdraw|  depos  |
+---------+--------+---------+
|   adaf  |   300  |      0  |
|   rich  |   1000 |    355  |
|   call  |     0  |     45  |
|   alen  |     0  |      0  |
|  courney|     0  |     106 |
|  warren |     0  |      0  |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

What's the problem? - I'm getting the wrong values in the result table. Exactly in `withdraw` and `depos`. They're in 4 times more, than they should be. For example, for some client `SUM(depos)` should be 500, but in my result table this value gets 2000. I guess, the problem is in a `GROUP BY` method, cause when I'm executing the following query, the result seems to look OK:

```
SELECT clientid, SUM(case when memo = 'Withdraw' then amount else 0 end) as withdraw, SUM(case when memo = 'Depos' then amount else 0 end) as depos
 from clients 
 LEFT JOIN 
 table2 
 ON
 clients.Fidx = table2.clientid
 WHERE table2.date >= '01-09-2016' and table2.date<='01-09-2017' GROUP BY clientid ORDER BY clientid;
```

**What can be a reason of such a wrong result? I'm in trouble and need your help, guys.**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So when the first query executes, it doesn't give you a result that looks like the sample table you provided? It might be easier to provide sample tables you pull from and desired results.

Comment: Your left join could be the culprit.  It could include a row multiple times for matching joins. Try using a sub-query for each sum.

Comment: @Simon it's a different values

Comment: @Simon just take those values and multyply by 4, and you'll get the result for 2 SUMs().

Comment: Side note: You're including 1 extra day in your range: a full "1 year" range would be `01-09-2016 to 01-08-2017` (the start of the next range would be the same day the next year).  Also, I've assumed the format was `mm-DD-YYYY`, but this is ambiguous (ie, could be `DD-mm-YYYY`) - please use the unambiguous format: `YYYYmmDD`, or `20170108`.  Lastly, don't use an inclusive upper-bound, you should use an exclusive (`<`); [otherwise you risk unintended data](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much answered this yourself with the bottom query.  You need to do the summing **before** the join, in a derived table or subquery, just like you have in the bottom query.  This will ensure you join on a many-to-one relationship, instead of a many-to-many, which must be causing your current duplication (or 'multiplied' sums).

```
SELECT 
                    MAX(table1.id) as id, 
                    clients.Username as account, 
                    table1.clientid, 
                    SUM(table1.symbols) as symbols, 
                    SUM(table1.tickets) as tickets, 
                    SUM(table1.cash) as cash, 
                    withdraw,
                    depos,
                FROM 
                    table1 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT clientid, 
                            SUM(case when memo = 'Withdraw' then amount else 0 end) as withdraw, 
                            SUM(case when memo = 'Depos' then amount else 0 end) as depos
                     FROM clients 
                     LEFT JOIN table2 ON clients.Fidx = table2.clientid
                     AND table2.date >= '01-09-2016' 
                     AND table2.date<='01-09-2017' 
                     GROUP BY clientid) clients                                                                        
                ON 
                    clients.clientID = table1.clientid 
                WHERE 
                    table1.tradedate >= '01-09-2016' 
                 AND 
                    table1.tradedate <= '01-09-2017'
                GROUP BY 
                    table1.clientid, clients.Username, table2.clientid, clients.depos, clients.withdraw
                ORDER BY 
                    clients.Username;
```

Further example:

```
Table1
id | someInfo
1  |  a
1  |  b
1  |  c

Table2
id | value
1  |   5
1  |   10
```

This query:

```
SELECT t1.id, SUM(t2.Value)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id --This will be many-to-many
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Will result in this:

```
Results
id | value
1  |  45   --sum of 45 because the `table2` values are triplicated from the join
```

Where this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, Value
FROM table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(Value) value
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY id) t2 on t1.id = t2.id --This will be many-to-one
```

Will result in this:

```
Results
id | value
1  |  15   --sum of 15 because the `table2` values are not triplicated from the join
```

Comment: `Column 'clients.withdraw' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` What's wrong? And why this column is linked to clients, instead of table2?

Comment: @ex1t3 Whoops, you need to add `depos` and `withdraw` to the outer `GROUP BY` now, since they are no longer aggregates.  And those columns are linked to `clients` now only because I named the derived table `clients`

Comment: Aaron, sorry if I did something wrong or just doesn't understand..hm, whatever. result table should contains all the users, but it shows only those, who have not `NULL` withdraw or depos. Whats going on with this `lleft join`?

Comment: @ex1t3 Hm.. Trying changing the `WHERE table2.date >= '01-09-2016' AND table2.date<='01-09-2017'` to `AND table2.date >= '01-09-2016' AND table2.date<='01-09-2017'` in the derived table

Comment: Changing the `WHERE` to `AND` will move those from the `WHERE` clause to the join predicate.  Having those filters in the `WHERE` clause will basically result in an `INNER JOIN`.  Side note, it shouldn't matter on your outer `WHERE` clause because both of those filters affect the left table.

Comment: @ex1t3 Haha, no problem mate

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate before joining:

```
select
  t1.id, 
  c.Username as account, 
  c.clientid, 
  t1.symbols, 
  t1.tickets, 
  t1.cash, 
  coalesce(t2.withdraw, 0) as withdraw,
  coalesce(t2.depos, 0) as depos
from clients c
join
(
  select 
    clientid,
    max(id) as id,
    sum(symbols) as symbols, 
    sum(tickets) as tickets, 
    sum(cash) as cash
  from table1
  where date >= '20160901' and date <= '20170901'
  group by clientid
) t1 on t1.clientid = c.fidx
left join
(
  select 
    clientid,
    sum(case when memo = 'Withdraw' then amount end) as withdraw,
    sum(case when memo = 'Depos' then amount end) as depos
  from table2
  where date >= '20160901' and date <= '20170901'
  group by clientid
) t2 on t2.clientid = c.fidx;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All I can do for you just to put up your rating